# How to override CSS with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i found custome code css like this

```css
header.type-2:not(.fixed-header) nav>ul>li>a{
 color:#000;
}
```

i'm trying override the color to #fff with javascript, but still no luck.

with this code below :

```js
<script>

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('header.type-2:not(.fixed-header) nav>ul>li>a');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.color = '#fff';
}

</script>
```

i cannot direct edit in css style, because i don't have permission for, but the interest is, i can execute simple javascript syntax like alert();

Please help me.

Comment: You can do this by jquery, btw your syntax is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not querying by class but by selector, use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('header.type-2:not(.fixed-header) nav>ul>li>a');
//console.log(elems)
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
   
    elems[i].style.color = '#f00';
}
```

```css
header.type-2:not(.fixed-header) nav>ul>li>a{
 color:#000;
}
```

```html
<header class="type-2">
  <nav><ul><li><a href="#">BOB</a></li></ul></nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByClassName` selects elements by their `class`, it does not work with a complex selector as in your example.

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` instead.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('header.type-2:not(.fixed-header) nav>ul>li>a');
```

Answer (score 0):

This beautyfull oneliner might do the trick. You just need to specify the function for it. What do you suppose should trick the event to change to `CSS`?

What it does is that it change the `width` from its previous value to the value written below. It could also be a variable. The `ClassToLookFor` is the `class` it will change the value on.

In below case I change the `width` of a `class` *IF* a specified `class` (here it is `tricker`) is present on the page (I use it for a more responsive webpage).

```
$(function(){
if (!$(".tricker").length) $(".ClassToLookFor").css('width', '100%');
});
```

Comment: Why introduce jQuery for this? You should write your answer in a way that references original question, not some other unrelated scenario?

Comment: Further more *if* you are using jQuery here, why not just `$('header.type-2:not(.fixed-header) nav>ul>li>a').css('color', '#FFF')`. Your `if` statement is completely not necessary.

Comment: jQuery are a language written to make JavaScript easier. You can say jQuery is JavaScript 2018. Yet you cannot use jQuery without knowing any JavaScript. I didn't remove the `IF` statement because questioner doesn't say what should trigger this event.

Comment: I strongly disagree that you can say "jQuery is Javascript 2018", you answer, at the very least, should mention it requires the jQuery library. The original question makes no reference to jQuery and is easily solvable without it. The original question states that they want to override the CSS style as they have no access to the CSS file. There is no trigger mentioned, as there is none, other than page load.